# how to get mvn help:describe to show phases of the default lifecycle

Tags: maven

Running `$ mvn help:describe -Dcmd=clean` tells you that 'clean' is a lifecycle, and lists its phases.  Similarly `$ mvn help:describe -Dcmd=site` tells you that 'site' is a lifecycle and lists its phases.

Is there any value for the `cmd` parameter of the `help:describe` goal that will list the phases of the default lifecycle?

Comment: What about `-Dcmd=package`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [cmd option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/describe-mojo.html#cmd) is "a single goal or a single phase" to describe.

While it is true that `clean` and `site` are the name of lifecycles, they are also the name of *phases* within [those lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.1/maven-core/lifecycles.html).

It also looks like the description the `help:describe` goal prints out is a bit misleading ([here's the source code](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/plugins/help/DescribeMojo.html#891)).  `cmd` is not actually "a lifecycle with the following phases", but the name of a particular phase within a lifecycle whose phases are listed.  You can prove this by trying `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=post-site` for example, and Maven prints out

```
'post-site' is a lifecycle with the following phases:
* pre-site: Not defined
* site: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site
* post-site: Not defined
* site-deploy: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:deploy
```

even though 'post-site' is the name of a *phase* and not a *lifecycle*.

As for printing out the phases of the default lifecycle, just set `cmd` to the name of any phase within the default lifecycle, such as `package` or `install` and it will print them out.

Just to be complete, the definitions for all the standard phases and lifecycles are in Maven's [components.xml](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.1/maven-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/plexus/components.xml#L35) and the the ID of the default lifecycle is 'default'.

Comment: +1 For pointing me to the source.  Looking at that conditional, it doesn't look like the code is behaving as intended.  Apparently if any phase of the default lifecycle is used as the value of the `cmd` parameter then the `if` branch is executed, whereas phases of the `site` and `clean` lifecycles trigger the `else` branch.  (I don't exactly understand why, since after a cursory glance at `Lifecycle.java` I don't see how `lifecycle.getDefaultPhases()` is ever non-null.)